# Functions in o(n) and ω(1)

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I was solving some question and I came across this one.

**Give a function which is both in o(n) (little-oh) and in ω(1) (little-omega), or state that none exists.**

I thought of functions like logn or sqrt(n).
However, I'm still doubtful whether such function will exist or not. Does a constant function make any difference

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.

Proof is based on set theory.

```
o(n) = O(n) \ Theta(n)
ω(1) = Omega(1) \ Theta(1)
```

You are looking for something that is in the intersection of `o(n)` and `ω(1)`
log(n) is in `O(n)`, and in `Omega(1)` - and not in Theta(n) nor Theta(1), so it is in the intersection, and thus fits.